# Smoothed landsat LST time series with lineair regression function

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series, smoothing, land-surface-temperature

I am trying to get a smoothed result in GEE from my LST time series but I get an error that the memory limit is exceeded.

How can I make my model more effective?

This is my code:

```
var LLST = require('users/sofiaermida/landsat_smw_lst:modules/Landsat_LST.js')

var addDataBands = function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
  var mask = cloud.lte(15);
  return image.addBands(LST).updateMask(mask)
              .addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(1e18).rename('time'));
};

var Lan8 = LLST.collection('L8', '2013', '2024', geometry2, true).sort('CLOUD_COVER').select('LST').map(function(image){
  return image.subtract(273.15).clip(geometry2).set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))
})

print("chart");
// print(Lan8)
print(
  ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: Lan8,
    region: geometry2,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 30,
    xProperty: 'system:time_start'
  }));

// Function to smooth time series
// stacks windows of linear regression results
// requires that a variable 'data' exists with LST and time bands
function smoother(t){
  // helper function to apply linear regression equation
  function applyFit(img){
      return img.select('time').multiply(fit.select('scale')).add(fit.select('offset'))
              .set('system:time_start',img.get('system:time_start')).rename('LST');
  }
  t = ee.Date(t);

  var window = data.filterDate(t.advance(-windowSize,'day'),t.advance(windowSize,'day'));

  var fit = window.select(['time','LST'])
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

  return window.map(applyFit).toList(5);
}

// function to reduce time stacked linear regression results
// requires that a variable 'fitIC' exists from the smoother function
function reduceFits(t){
  t = ee.Date(t);
  return fitIC.filterDate(t.advance(-windowSize,'day'),t.advance(windowSize,'day'))
              .mean().set('system:time_start',t.millis()).rename('LST');
}

var data = Lan8;
print(data);

var dates = ee.List(data.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var windowSize = 40; //days on either side

var fitIC = ee.ImageCollection(dates.map(smoother).flatten());

var smoothed = ee.ImageCollection(dates.map(reduceFits));

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: smoothed,
  region: geometry2,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30
}).setOptions({title: 'LST over time'});

print(chart);


// merge original and smoothed data into one image collection for plotting
var joined = smoothed.select(['LST'], ['smoothed']).merge(data.select(['LST'], ['original']));
                
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: joined,
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30
}).setOptions({title: 'LST over time'});

print(chart);
```